# Keep only first word in Column RSQLite

Tags: r, rsqlite

I am working on tranferring SQL code over to R.

I have a dataset and want to extract the first word from a column in a new column.

Dataset

```
 df

        Col_A    ColB
  ABC JEn JDn       9
  nemmdn mend      10
pwek ne me ne      12
```

Expected Output:

```
        Col_A    ColB    Col_A_Abbreviation
  ABC JEn JDn       9                   ABC
  nemmdn mend      10                nemmdn
pwek ne me ne      12                  pwek
```

Below is what I have currently:

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
mydb <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "")
dbWriteTable(mydb, "df_1", df)

dbGetQuery(mydb, 
'SELECT IF(INSTRB(Col_A, \' \', 1, 1) >0, 
SUBSTR(Col_A, 1, INSTRB(Col_A, \' \', 1, 1) - 1), 
Col_A) AS Col_A_Abbreviation FROM df_1')
```

Here is my error message:

```
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : no such function: IF
```

Does RSQLite have limitations on what functions it can use?

Comment: SQLite uses `CASE`

Comment: Thanks, when I do that, now it says `Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "AS": syntax error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) sqldf/RSQLite** If you are using the SQLite backend then you can only use functions supported by RSQLite.  Try this where `df` is defined reproducibly in the Note at the end.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select 
    *, 
    substr([Col_A], 1, instr([Col_A], ' ') - 1) FirstWord 
  from df")
```

giving:

```
          Col_A ColB FirstWord
1   ABC JEn JDn    9       ABC
2   nemmdn mend   10    nemmdn
3 pwek ne me ne   12      pwek
```

**1a)** If there can be entries with only one word then append a space to the end to ensure that there is always at least one space to match.

```
sqldf("select 
    *, 
    substr([Col_A], 1, instr([Col_A] || ' ', ' ')-1) FirstWord 
  from df")
```

**2) Base R**

In base R remove the first space and everything after it:

```
transform(df, FirstWord = sub(" .*", "", Col_A))
```

### Note

```
df <-
structure(list(`Col_A` = c("ABC JEn JDn", "nemmdn mend", "pwek ne me ne"
), `ColB` = c(9L, 10L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the comment from Clemsang, why not use `strsplit()` after getting the result from the dataset?

Something like this:

```
a <- c("ABC Jen JDn", "nemmdn mend", "pwek ne me ne")
b <- sapply(strsplit(a, " "), "[", 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I need it to be done in SQL though unfortunately

Comment: Then you should add `CASE`, `WHEN` and `THEN` to your query like Clemsang suggested. See here: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-case/